# How to translate view in php using poedit

Tags: php, poedit, language-translation

I am currently working on a project. this is completely in `PHP` with `Bootstrap UI`. I want to translate it into `French`.

I have an Idea about POEDIT in wordpress. but I am not getting how can I translate a pure PHP project.

Can I use `poedit` to translate the PHP code. If yes, then after getting Messages in message folder, I can I configure them that if a person select a language then how can I access my message folder related to french language ?